# Mobile nav displaying clickable elements underneath dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a mobile nav following this tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IF6k0uZuypA.

The nav dropdown as show in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg3wV.png) is fully opaque and nothing behind dropdown shows through. However, only on the 'reviews list' page, where the sort by and add review elements are, the elements underneath the dropdown show and mess the mobile nav up, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4efS.jpg).

I am using React, MUI material icons https://mui.com/components/material-icons/ for the 'add' icon and MUI select for the sort and order by https://mui.com/components/selects/.

I have switched the add icon from MUI and replaced it with Fontawesome, but the issue still appears.

I have also tried setting the Z-index of the dropdown to 1 and the Z-index of the add icon underneath to -1, but this only seems to disable the add element under the dropdown.

I have also tried adding an 'opacity: 1' to the dropdown, this does not seem to change anything either.

```
// navbar css

* {
  margin: 0px;
}

:root {
  --bg: #242526;
  --bg-accent: #484a4d;
  --nav-size: 60px;
  --border: 1px solid #474a4d;
  --border-radius: 8px;
  --speed: 500ms;
  margin-top: 75px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
} 

a {
  /* color: #dadce1; */
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  color: #dadce1;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  height: var(--nav-size);
  background-color: var(--bg);
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border-bottom: var(--border);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-list {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav-item {
  width: calc(var(--nav-size) * 0.8);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.icon-button {
  --button-size: calc(var(--nav-size) * 0.5);
  width: var(--button-size);
  height: var(--button-size);
  /* background-color: #484a4d;  */
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 56px;
  width: 300px;
  transform: translateX(-35%);
  background-color: rgb(16, 85, 211);
  border: var(--border);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  opacity: 1;
}

.menu-item {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  /* transition: background var(--speed);  */
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

 .menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #525357;
} 

.nav-profile-pic {
  max-width: 75px;
}
```

```
// review-list css

button, .sort-by {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Your Netlify App is stuck on *"Loading"* but anyways questions here on Stack Overflow are supposed to include a [mcve], not images or links to external sites that might go down one day and be help - nobody. Please [edit], read [ask]

Comment: If I'm guessing right, just add some `position` other than `static` on the element with `z-index`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thank you. But if I add any position to the add icon and sort by elements underneath the dropdown, the dropdown works great but then the add icon and sort by are unclickable as if they have been disabled.

Comment: I cannot see any HTML in your example code above. Please add some Minimal HTML as well - that reproduces your problem.

Comment: `.navbar` has position fixed but no z-index like i.e: `z-index: 1000;`  set.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan amazing that worked!! Thank you so much. So I'm assuming because I gave dropdown a z-index, I had to give the parent element navbar a z-index too?

Comment: Exactly Kristy! Since, if a parent element has a Z-index, the children will "inherit" it (well, not exactly *inherit* but yeah, you got the point.). You're very welcome. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By just seeing your CSS, the easiest would be:

add `z-index: 1000;` (or any needed value) to the *`position: fixed;`* **parent**  element `.navBar`.
Its child elements will perform accordingly - overlaying other elements on the page.

[Z-index MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)
and keep in mind to use z-index on elements with CSS having `positon` (other than `: static;`)

Comment: @RokoCBulijan means by large z-index value, that element will come to the surface.

Comment: @ash thanks for the addendum, but OP's does know already the meaning of z-indexing an element. I added a link for anyone else willing to explore some Docs.

Comment: I didn't know clearly that's why I wrote sorry. @Roko C.Buljan